# Can I have more than 1 diaglog box in a class?

Tags: android, dialog, android-dialog

I'm developing an image editing app. And I'm stuck at some point. I'm using a dialog box to show a list of effects on click of a button(say the FX button.). It works fine but then i tried using that second button say color, to display another dialog box, but i cant. I had to import that dialog box class for the first button i.e FX. And importing another dialog box class causes a conflict with the first import.

What should I do? And I have 3 buttons so I'll need to have 3 dialog boxes. 
So is there any way I can get this to work?
Please help!!!

Comment: This is what i did to import the classes:
import my.app.efxcamera.FxAlertDialogRadio.AlertPositiveListener;
import my.app.efxcamera.color.ColorAlertDialogRadio.AlertPositiveListener;


This is the error:
The import my.app.efxcamera.color.ColorAlertDialogRadio.AlertPositiveListener collides with another import statement

Comment: show how you have done it

Comment: remove the `.AlertPositiveListener` at the end of both `import` statements and then refer to them as `ColorAlertDialogRadio.AlertPositiveListener` and `FxAlertDialogRadio.AlertPositiveListener` in your code respectively. that will solve the conflict

Answer (score 0):

You got 2 choices.

(1) Create a wrapper class for your second DialogBox.

```
public class SecondDialogBox extends DialogBox
{
}
```

(2) Don't use import. Just use the full package name as suggested by Thrakbad.

```
com.full.package.name.DialogBox dialog = new com.full.package.name.DialogBox();
```

Comment: Did you remove it from the import line? You don't need to declare import when you use full package name.